# CoreData Application Freezes while performing a fetch Request pthread_mutex_lock

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, ios5, core-data

I am using Core Data for managing data base into my app.

I can not post the code here, because its too lengthy. But I guess that I can explain my problem in small line of code along with some snap shots.

```
+(NSArray *)checkusernameandpassword:(NSString *)entityname  username:(NSString *)username   password:(NSString *)password 
{
    managedobjectcontext=[Singleton sharedmysingleton].managedobjectcontext;
    NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityname inManagedObjectContext:managedobjectcontext];

    NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicates=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userName==\"%@\" AND password==\"%@\"",username,password]];
    [request setPredicate:predicates];  
    //On Below line, My app frezes and goes into deadlock, this happens randomly while performing
    //some data request using Core data
    NSArray *arrayofrecord=[managedobjectcontext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];    

    return arrayofrecord;
}
```

I am trying to attach some screen shots of the stack of calls (These I see when I pause my app)
**The method with a checkmark in the image,at which deadlock occur is mentioned above**
[image: The method with a checkmark in the image,at which deadlock occur is mentioned above]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to lock the thread. This problem appears when multiple threads access the same piece of code. But be were not to end up in to a dead lock.

```
static NSString *fetchRequest = @"fetchRequest";
    NSArray *results;
    @synchronized (fetchRequest){
        managedobjectcontext=[Singleton sharedmysingleton].managedobjectcontext;
        NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityname inManagedObjectContext:managedobjectcontext];

        NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
       [request setEntity:entity];

       NSPredicate *predicates=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userName==\"%@\" AND password==\"%@\"",username,password]];
       [request setPredicate:predicates];  
       //On Below line, My app frezes and goes into deadlock, this happens randomly while performing
       //some data request using Core data
       results = [managedobjectcontext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];    
}
return results;
```

Comment: Hello @AlexTerente, would you mind taking a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504936/core-data-executefetchrequest-freezes-app-in-a-background-thread) and tell me if your solution might also apply there?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand from your dump, you are calling CoreData Context within a different thread other than MainThread.

Keep in mind that CoreData Context are not thread safe and is your responsability to correct use it.

[Apple documentation about CoreData and Thread](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) is very exhaustive.

The solutions proposed above are not safe at all: synchronized statement is useless if you are programming in a concurrent environment (ie. you have more than one thread that we assume can access concurrently the same MOC).

You can try to "confine" your context within the thread life-cycle. For example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^(){
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
context.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator;

//Make the fetch and export results to main thread
...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try `[private performBlock:^{}];` when using Core Data in multi-thread environment.

For more details, please check this document https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH24-SW1